# Catkin_make complains about non-existing CMakeLists.txt

Tags: catkin-make, catkin, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm encountering a really strange error: **catkin_make** complains about a non-existing CMakeLists.txt:

```
andreas@andreas-lab: catkin_make install
Base path: /home/andreas/baxter_ws
Source space: /home/andreas/baxter_ws/src
Build space: /home/andreas/baxter_ws/build
Devel space: /home/andreas/baxter_ws/devel
Install space: /home/andreas/baxter_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/andreas/baxter_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/andreas/baxter_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/andreas/baxter_ws/install" in "/home/andreas/baxter_ws/build"
####
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/andreas/baxter_ws/src" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

However, the *CMakeLists.txt* file is clearly there:

```
andreas@andreas-lab: ls -1 src/
baxter
baxter_common
baxter_examples
baxter_interface
baxter_tools
CMakeLists.txt
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199076/catkin_make-complains-about-non-existing-cmakelists.txt/) by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 529 on 2014-12-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try running `catkin_init_workspace` in our catkin_ws/src folder.... Is the CMakelists.txt really a sym link to top-level cmake as it should be (Asure with `ll`)?

```
$ ll
.......
CMakeLists.txt -> /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake  
.......
```

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0